# Highlighting lines in validation

Tags: java, swing, validation

I want to highlight the lines which are errors while validating, I am currently using jtextarea, looked into jtextpane and styles, i need some suggestions in implementing like the below way.  Should i have to take jtextarea or jtextpane or any other best and easy option? thanks

```
private void validate(String text){
   lines = text.split("\n");

   for(String line : lines){
      if(line.substring(0, 1).equals("")){
           //want to highlight the entire line in red color
      } else {
         //remove the highlight
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
textarea.getHighligter().addHighlight()
```

See the doc [DefaultHighlighter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultHighlighter.html) and [Demos and Usage of DefaultHighlighter](http://www.javadocexamples.com/javax/swing/text/DefaultHighlighter/DefaultHighlightPainter/DefaultHighlightPainter%28Color%20c%29.html)

Comment: links to outdated api doc will make @Andrew unhappy, as you know :-)

Answer (score 2):

`JTextArea` will certainly not work as it only supports plain text. You will need a `JTextPane`. A handy overview (as I always forget which one does what) can be found in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)

For your validation, I would add a `DocumentListener` which validates the input and changes the color depending on the state.